# Is there any way to make the train leave the station?

Tags: red-dead-redemption

I'm trying to get one of the survivalist mastery levels that requires you to shoot birds from a moving train. I found the train sitting idle in one of the stations, but couldn't find any way to make it leave for the next station.

The conductor is sitting in the engine, he just won't make it go. I went to the ticket booth, no luck. I sat down on a seat in the train, still nothing. I waited a full day and there it still sits. Am I doing something wrong or missing something?

Comment: Have you tried saving the game, exiting, and then reloading?

Comment: This happened to me too, must be pretty common. I thought it might have had something to do with the bridge being damaged a while back. I felt like a proper moron after spending a day at the roof of an idle train, waving my Springfield at passing vultures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trains will normally start back up automatically after a certain amount of time passes. That amount of time differs depending on the reason the train stopped (reaching a station vs. stopping because an animal is in the way).

However, there is a [documented bug](http://reddead.wikia.com/wiki/Trains#Bugs) where the train stops and never starts back up:

> Occasionally, the red/blue train will stop and then not move again until you restart your console. You can still save your game before you reset as this will not make the bug/glitch permanent. Also an escape to the dashboard can resolve this.